# Show that the groups $SL_2(\mathbb{F}_3)$ and $S_4$ are two nonisomorphic groups of order 24.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-isomorphism

I proved that $$SL_2(\mathbb{F}_3)=\left\langle \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}\right\rangle$$ and know that $$S_4=\langle (1\ 2),(1\ 2\ 3\ 4)\rangle.$$ Is it enough to say that the order of each generator is different so any isomorphism $$\varphi:SL_2(\mathbb{F}_3)\to S_4$$ sending generators to generators would fail?

Comment: But generators are not unique.

Comment: Ok so it could be possible to find a pair of generators where this does not fail. I see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generators are not unique, so it's not so simple. I'll give a hint for a solution: $SL_2(\mathbb{F_3})$ has an element of order $6$.

Comment: I can think about the elements of $S_4$ and use the fact that the order of a permutation is the l.c.m. of the lengths of the cycles in its cycle decomposition. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you understood it right. So it's easy to see $S_4$ can't have any elements of order $6$.

Comment: No, $SL(2,3)$ is not so simple, it is solvable...

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to turn your idea into a correct argument.

To do this, you need to show that $S_4$ cannot be generated by elements of order  $3$. And this follows by noting that all such elements are contained in the proper subgroup $A_4$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $1\neq-1$ in $\Bbb F_3$ the group ${\rm SL}_2({\Bbb F_3})$ has a non-trivial centre.

On the other hand the centre of ${\cal S}_4$ is trivial.